# Mongoose Schema extend timestamp to have new properties (username)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I´m using `MongoDB` and `mongoose` for a project that needs to track data creation and changes. The requirements are that I need to keep track of records creation and changes including the date/time **and the application user** (not the OS user) who did it.

I´ve seen the mongoose [timestamps](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps) option that would solve my date/time issue, but is there a way to extend it to include extra properties, where I´m gonna be adding the application username ?

If not, is there a single place where I can write a function that will be called on every creation/update so that I can include/modify these fields ?

Today I´m insering these properties on every model like below, but I would like to move all of them to a single place.

```
var companySchema = mongoose.Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    phone: {
        type: String
    },
    deleted: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date
    },
    createdBy: {
        type: String
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: Date
    },
    updatedBy: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

How would be the best approach for it ?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it by creating two models, one for **each Data created**, one for **each Data Changes**.

Data created which will have 6 fields one is **createdBy**, **createdAt**, and one will be a field with an **array of reference id** of Data Changes, **deletedBy**, **deletedAt**, **deletedFlag**.

Data Changes will have fields **dataID** which will have reference id of data created, **updatedBy** and **updatedAt**.

This way it will be easy to keep track of when it was created when it was changes and when it was deleted.

PS: You can remove either of Array in Data created model or dataID ref id in Data Change mode, it was just me being extra cautious while binding.